# Switch on enum method thread error

Tags: java, enums

I am getting "Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NullPointerException at client.Client.run(Client.java:32)" line 32 is the switch statement line below. The switch is on a enum method.  I think the error is a from one of the threads going faster than the other but i'm unsure... I hope i've provided enough code here if not I will add more let me know what I need to add.

```
public void run()    {
            while (running) {
                try {
                    switch (receiveMessage()) {
                        case SERVER_HELLO:
                            expectingServerHello = true;
                            break;
                            //other cases
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

public ServerMessages receiveMessage() throws IOException {
        String sentence;
        BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        sentence = inFromServer.readLine();
        return MessageSerialize.fromServerMessage(sentence);
    }
```

Comment: can `MessageSerialize.fromServerMessage(sentence);` return null? if so then there's your problem

Comment: Please post your exception's stacktrace. Please indicate which line throws the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the error is at that switch line, the obvious reason seems to be that you are doing a `switch (null)`, aka, your `receiveMessage()` returns NULL, and you're not expecting that (because you've but it right there in the switch.

Either check for it being `NULL`, and do whatever you want in that case (exception, nothing, depens :)  ), or fix that function so it never returns `NULL` anymore..